# Android JNI java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/example/package/InternalWrapper$1;.InternalCallback(IILjava/lang/String;[B)V"
```

Interface:

```
interface InternalDelegate {
   void InternalCallback(int var1, int var2, String var3, byte[] var4);
}
```

Class:

```
package com.example.package;

public class InternalWrapper implements InternalDelegate {

@Override
    public void InternalCallback(int var1, int var2, String var3, byte[] var4) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "InternalCallback() !!!!!!!!!!!");
    }

}
```

JNI part:

```
// Prepare the Java callback
jmethodID methodId = env->GetMethodID(m_delegate_class, "InternalCallback", "(IILjava/lang/String;[B)V");
```

And the question is what is wrong here?
I could overlook something so please check from Your site.

**SOLUTION:**
Guys below has right. Delegate class is setting by "this" and I did it in anonymous class.

Comment: `com/example/package/InternalWrapper$1` is an anonymous class? This does not match your example. I'd expect it to say just `com/example/package/InternalWrapper`.

Comment: Yes, where does `m_delegate_class` come from? Do you maybe get it from an object instance where you pass in some `this` inside an anonymous class instead of `InternalWrapper.this`? (just guessing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** 
Guys in the comments has right.
 Delegate class is setting by "this" and I did it in anonymous class.